# While assigning value to a variable it says syntax error in python

Tags: python, syntax-error

this variable y shows syntax error whenever I try to run it

```
print('Check if your no. is odd or even!')
x=int(input('Insert no.')
y=x%2
if a==0:
 print('Your no. is even')
else:
 print('Your no. is odd')
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket at the end of the line `x=int(...`

Comment: What is `a`? Do you mean `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have lost ')' in:

```
x=int(input('Insert no.')) <- close bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing parentheses when defining x. Here is the corrected code:

```
x=int(input('Insert no.'))
```

Comment: Also, as @schwobaseggl said, I think you mean `y` not `a`